# list their numbers?

Tags: phrase-usage

Suppose that I want to ask someone to choose the fruits he or she likes from a list, and those fruits are marked with a number. What should I say?

> Please list their numbers.

> Please list them in numbers.

> Please specify their numbers.

> Please specify them in numbers.

Comment: Try to ask questions that are about real problems that you have faced rather than hypothetical situations.  I have never asked someone to choose fruit from a numbered list.  If I did, I assume the context would be sufficient.  Why would you need to restrict the answers to "What fruit do you like" to a list?  Why would you insist on getting number answers?

Comment: "Please note down the numbers of the chosen fruits."

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> Here is a list of fruits. Please specify the ones you like by listing their numbers.

Comment: Does this work? Here is a list of fruits. Joe likes six of them. Please list their corresponding numbers"?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, that works.